# Disable/Enable WPF contextmenu item programmatically

Tags: .net, wpf, contextmenu

How to modify a specific `ContextMenu` `MenuItem` programmatically when the `ContextMenu` has a `Separator` in it?

In the parent control I have

```
ContextMenuOpening="ModifyItems"
```

The `ContextMenu` is

```
<ContextMenu >
    <MenuItem Header="Item1" Tag="SomeTag" />
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem Header="Item2" />                                                     
</ContextMenu>
```

I handle the `ContextMenuOpening` (according to Microsoft example)

```
Private Sub ModifyItems(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuEventArgs)
        Dim fe As FrameworkElement = TryCast(e.Source, FrameworkElement)
        Dim cm As ContextMenu = fe.ContextMenu
        For Each mi As MenuItem In cm.Items
            If CType(mi.Tag, String) = "SomeTag" Then
                mi.IsEnabled = IsEnabled()
            End If
        Next mi
End Sub
```

I run into exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Separator' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem'.

How to resolve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the item is a `MenuItem`:

```
For Each i In cm.Items
    If TypeOf i Is MenuItem Then
        Dim mi = CType(i, MenuItem)
        If CType(mi.Tag, String) = "SomeTag" Then
            mi.IsEnabled = IsEnabled()
        End If
    End If
Next mi
```